# Is it possible to use MSAL UserAgentApplication configuration (authority) to restrict login access to a particular Azure AD Security Group?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I've built a react app (using CRA) and am attempting to secure it using MSAL.js, granting access to only those people within an Azure AD Security Group. The following doc suggests it might be possible to do just this through configuration, by setting the 'authority' property:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-initializing-client-applications

e.g. `Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>`

where the  is a "GUID representing the TenantID property of the directory used only to sign in users of a specific organization"

1. What does 'directory' mean in this context?
2. Should I be able to use the Tenant ID of the Security Group here too?

Comment: Hi, any concern about this issue? If not, please accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> What does 'directory' mean in this context?

It means the Azure AD Directory, in general, we also called it Azure AD Tenant.

You can find the `Tenant ID` in the portal -> Azure Active Directory.

[image]

> Should I be able to use the Tenant ID of the Security Group here too?

Yes, you could use the `Tenant ID` in your case.